# Ionic show keyboard without input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am doing an Ionic/Angular application and I would like to ask if I can press a button to show keyboard without input element? If I cannot do so, the best way to perform is to make a invisible input and hide all the border, outline, input stroke and retrieve the input onchange value?

Update:
I am currently doing this but this cannot detect a backspace key press when the text field is empty.

```
<ion-input (ionInput)="inputChange($event)" class="input" [attr.maxlength]="1"></ion-input>
```

What I am going to do is to perform something like the following image. By clicking any box, it will show a mobile keyboard.

[image]

Comment: use Keyboard Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can **set focus()** in the input field to activate the keyboard automatically. So, do the necessary imports and follow the example.

In the .html file:

```
<ion-input #autofocus type="text" formControlName="userName" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome"></ion-input>
```

In the .ts file:

```
@ViewChild('autofocus', {static: false}) inputElement: IonInput;
```

Also on AfterViewInit function:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.inputElement.setFocus();
  }, 300);
}
```

Comment: why did you do setTimeout 300ms ? A little explanation would be good. This is not reactive now right? So if the inputElement takes longer than 300ms to get ready for whatever reason (e.g. slow client-device) then this would result in the input not getting focused?

Comment: @ChefLax thanks for asking. So, using the ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle means that at the time this function is called the setFocus() will be executed in 300ms. The human eyes cannot be faster than this. But sure, you can put 1 over there and the final result can be almost the same. It is just an example, try it as you want... Please, if it solves your problems let an upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a "faster" and also probably more reliable way than the other answer that waited 300ms with a timeout:

https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/set-auto-focus-ionic-input-ionic-6-and-angular-13

```
<ion-input #emailInput type="text" value="" [formControlName]="'username'"> 
</ion-input>

import {AfterViewChecked, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from 
'@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from 
'@angular/forms';
import {IonInput} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.page.html'
})

@AutoUnsubscribe
export class LoginPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked {
public loginForm!: FormGroup;
focusIsSet!: boolean;
@ViewChild('emailInput', {static: false}) emailInput!: IonInput;

constructor(
    private readonly fb: FormBuilder,
) {...}

public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  if (!this.focusIsSet) {
    this.emailInput.setFocus();
    // Disable focus on setTimeout()
    // Timeout needed for buggy behavior otherwise!
  setTimeout(() => {this.focusIsSet = true; }, 1000);
  }
}
}
```

Basically it works by retrying until it works. But even this solution could be improved. You might want to set a max number of tries and delay to only try every 100ms with a setInterval. And then do this inside ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: You don't need to wait 300ms of course! See my explanation below.